# Can't build angular 4 project using systemjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, systemjs

I'm using Angular 4 with VS 2017 (ASP 5 Web Api) +systemjs.
I'm trying to build Angular application for production,I've added 2 dependencies in
  **package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    .....
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "systemjs-builder": "0.16.11"
  }
```

I've created  create **gulpfile.js** in asp project root folder

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  Builder = require('systemjs-builder');


gulp.task('bundle-angular-dependencies', function() {
  // optional constructor options
  // sets the baseURL and loads the configuration file
  var builder = new Builder('', 'systemjs.config.js');

  return builder
    .bundle('app/boot.js - [app/**/*.js]', 'path/to/put/angular.bundle.js', { minify: true})
    .then(function() {
      console.log('Build complete');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Build error');
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

then in root folder of project I've run :

```
gulp bundle-angular-dependencies
```

and got

```
Build error
Error: Unable to calculate canonical name to bundle file:///app/boot.js. Ensure that this module sits within the baseURL or a wildcard path config.
    at getCanonicalNamePlain (D:\myapp\node_modules\systemjs-builder\lib\utils.js:227:13)
    at getCanonicalName (D:\myapp\node_modules\systemjs-builder\lib\utils.js:150:19)
    at D:\myapp\node_modules\systemjs-builder\lib\arithmetic.js:171:38
    at <anonymous>
[18:50:43] Finished 'bundle-angular-dependencies' after 604 ms
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the new built-in Angular templates for Visual Studio 2017?

File | New | Project

Select the ASP.NET Core Web Application template

Then in the "New ASP.NET Core Web Application" dialog, select Angular.

[image]

Comment: Hi Deborah,I'm not using ASP Core,I'm using ASP 5.I think that will not work.thanks

Comment: Have you seen this: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx ASP.NET 5 *is* Asp.NET Core.

Comment: I know.but my db provider not fully support Core now.thanks